# How to access each row and each column value of array in php?

Tags: php

My code is....

```
<?php
include_once 'Includes\dba.php';

$data = array();

// Fetch comment from DB for certain module and save in array
$sql="SELECT Comment FROM module_feedback_comments WHERE module_id=1";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{



while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
}

$data2=array('success','t');
foreach ($data as $d)
{
    echo $d['Comment']."<br>";
    //echo gettype($d['Comment']);
    $data2=  array_merge($data2,explode(" ", $d['Comment']));
}


//counting values present in array for case insensitive by changing each array element to lowercase
$result=array_count_values(array_map("strtolower", $data2));


print_r($result); //Result 2*/

?>
```

Now this is giving result as:

```
Array ( [success] => 1 [t] => 1 [this] => 7 [is] => 7 [a] => 2 [comment] => 2 [comment2] => 1 [nnnnnnn] => 1 [fffff] => 1 [weee] => 1 [dd] => 1 [mon] => 1 [mooo] => 1 [monday] => 1 [pak] => 1 [mm] => 1 [mmmmmmm] => 1 [all] => 1 [comments] => 2 [ttt] => 1 [last] => 1 [tt] => 2 [so] => 2 [thi] => 2 [os.....] => 2 [si] => 1 [...] => 1 [too] => 1 [ff] => 1 [testing] => 1 [to] => 1 [my] => 1 )
```

What I want is that i can print like :

```
success 1
t  1
this 7
```

So how i can do this ? Also how i can access value in each row or column of array ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop as

```
foreach($result as $key=>$val){
  echo $key." ".$val;
  echo "<br>";       
}
```